# Xamarin UITest REPL Query TableView elements

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-test-cloud, xamarin.uitest

How can I list the elements from TableView using REPL? I need all the elements with class `UIAccessibilityElementMockView`. These are the elements that are visible after tree command:
[Xamarin_Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmm4b.png)

I've tried already the following commands:

```
app.Query(x=>x.Class("UITableView").Child())
app.Query(x=>x.Class("UITableView").Child("UITableViewCell"))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After investigating a while, I managed to solve this one:

**app.Query(x => x.Class("UITableViewCell").Descendant("UIBUttonLabel"))**

This query is returning the list off all the entities I need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `app.Query(c => c.Marked("UIAccessibilityElementMockView"))`?

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery.Marked/

Could you possibly post a sample app?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it without success. For the Android project I manage to do it like app.Query(x=>x.Class("EntityListView").Child("EntityView")). But still no luck with iOS part.

Comment: @miskegm, could you post a more detailed sample? maybe a github link?